# How to save an onActivityResult result?

Tags: android

i have created a `MainActivity` and a `SecondActivity`. When `onClick` `MainActivity` it starts the `SecondActivity`. When `SecondActivity` finish, it returns a value that turns an `ImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` and makes a `counter++`.

My problem is that when i close the application and then restart it again all the values were cleared and my `ImageView` turns `ImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` and the `counter == 0` again.

How can i save data (the result of `SecondActivity`) even if i close the aplication or reboot my mobile? I want to set `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {` as before i close the application each time i restart it.

---

What I want is to save "int contadorliga", "correcto1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);" and "correcto2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);" so each time I restar the app it is as the latest time it was. This is my code:

```
package com.fakur.android.futbolquiz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Liga extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

static final int LIGA = 0;
int contadorbarcelona = 0;
int contadormadrid = 0;
int contadorliga = 0;

ImageView about;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.liga);
TextView contador1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contador1);
contador1.setText(contadorliga + "/20");
}

public void onBarcelonaClick(View botton) {

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this,Pregunta.class);
intent.putExtra("Barcelona", "Barcelona");
startActivityForResult(intent,LIGA);
}

public void onMadridClick(View botton) {

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(this,Pregunta.class));
intent.putExtra("Madrid", "Madrid");
startActivityForResult(intent,LIGA);
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

TextView contador1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contador1);
ImageView correcto1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.correcto1);
ImageView correcto2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.correcto2);

if (requestCode == LIGA){

  if (resultCode == 1) {

      if(contadorbarcelona == 0){

          correcto1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          contadorliga++ ;
          contadorbarcelona++;
      }
  }

  if (resultCode == 2) {
      if(contadormadrid == 0){

           correcto2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           contadorliga++ ;
           contadormadrid++;
      }
  }

}

contador1.setText(contadorliga + "/20");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage of shared preferences is best fit for you, see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Edit:

- Added source below in response to your comment;

  ```
  private static final String PREFERENCES_CONTADORLIGA =  "ChangeThisTextWithSomethingYouPrefer";
  private static final String PREFERENCES_CONTADORLIGA_KEY = "ChangeThisTextWithSomethingYouPrefer";


  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {

      // Restore preferences
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_CONTADORLIGA, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      contadorliga = settings.getInt(PREFERENCES_CONTADORLIGA_KEY, 0);
  }



  protected void onDestroy() 
  {

      super.onDestroy();

      // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
      // All objects are from android.context.Context
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_CONTADORLIGA, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putInt(PREFERENCES_CONTADORLIGA_KEY, contadorliga);

      // Commit the edits!
      editor.commit();
  }
  ```

I hope this should work for you. Good Luck!

Comment: thanks but i can't do it right. I have written my code, could you look at it please?

Comment: thank you very much, contadorliga works good. But how can I save correcto1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); ?

Answer (score 2):

if your dataset is not huge, just like Gokhan suggested, using shared preference is really good for you.

while, if you have a lot of similar datas to store, using sqlite3 database to store your datas. [Link](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html).

Also, store the datas in your onStop() function.

Comment: thanks but i can't do it right. I have written my code, could you look at it please?